# Different string representation of a filehandle reference in Perl

Tags: perl

I did the exercise 8.2 from [Intermediate Perl](http://www.intermediateperl.com/). It looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my %fhs;    # filehandles

while (<>) {
    unless (/^\s*(\S[^:]+):/) {
        warn "ignoring line with missing name: $_";
        next;
    }   
    my $castaway = lc $1; 

    unless ( $fhs{$castaway} ) { 
        my $fh = IO::File->new( $castaway . '.info', 'w' );
        #open my $fh, '>', "$castaway.info";
        $fhs{$castaway} = $fh;
    }   

    print { $fhs{$castaway} } $_; 
}   

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%fhs;
```

(You can download sample data to run the program on from the [download page](http://www.intermediateperl.com/downloads_page/) - see Chapter 8).

I tried to get the filehandles via one of these two ways:

```
my $fh = IO::File->new( $castaway . '.info', 'w' );
open my $fh, '>', "$castaway.info";
```

I guess they are equivalent but when I dump the `%fhs` hash contents I get different results. Why do they differ? What does it mean? Thanks.

Comment: What _do_ you get when you dump them? But I'm guessing - in one you've got an `IO::File` object, and the other you've got a scalar

Comment: Using `IO::File` I get `bless( \*Symbol::GEN4, 'IO::File' )` where the `GEN<n>` part is different for different hash keys and with the `open` I get the same `\*{'::$_[...]'}` for all keys.

Answer (score 2):

`IO::File` is an object oriented interface to a file handle. Inside, it's doing the same thing, but the `IO::File` module has a bunch of built in methods for interacting with your filehandle.

If you have a look at the doc: http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/File.html

You'll see this at work - when you use `new` the result is an instance of an `IO::File` object, and you can call methods within it via `->`.

E.g.

```
$fh -> close();
```

This is a different `close` to the perl built in, although it does basically the same thing.

Behind the scenes, within the `IO::File` module, you'll probably find a "real" filehandle buried within, but without needing to mess around with the perl operators for autoflush, buffering, line endings etc.

If you look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.htmlyou'll see there's a bunch of globals that change behaviour of files:

> $|
>   If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or print on the currently selected output channel.
>
> $/
>   The input record separator, newline by default. This influences Perl's idea of what a "line" is.

etc. `IO::File` hides these behind an OO layer.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles